# How do I upload file using CGI APPLICATION

Tags: perl, file-upload, cgi-application

Hi 
I am trying to upload image file using perl cgi-application. Not sure what I am doing wrong - but an empty image file (with the right name)  gets saved.

---

my $picture = $self->query->param('picture') ; 
my $buffer; 
my $bytesread;

open (OUTFILE, ">>$user_dir/profile_picture/$picture");
while ($bytesread = read($picture, $buffer, 1024)) {
    print OUTFILE $buffer;
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the " CREATING A FILE UPLOAD FIELD" section of [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~lds/CGI.pm-3.50/lib/CGI.pm) documentation. There you will see that the upload method will return a filehandle.

```
    my $fh = $self->query->upload('picture');

    my $buffer; my $bytesread;
    while ($bytesread = read($fh, $buffer, 1024)) {
      ...
     }
```

Comment: I saw that, the upload method however works only with plain old CGI not with cgi::application

Comment: Since `query()` returns a plain old `CGI` object, it should work just fine.

Comment: That's what I expected - but it doesn't. Others have complained about it in forums. its probably a bug in cgi::application.

Comment: Rest assured that there is no bug in CGI::Application affecting file uploads. I use it all the time. There is a bug somwhere in you code or in your HTML/Javascript. Maybe what Aquatoad says.

Comment: I found it. This was what I was missing - binmode OUTFILE; - it handles non-text formats

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your HTML form element also needs to specify enctype='multipart/mixed', otherwise  the upload filestream doesn't get sent.